# Why is my reference to ProgressDialog wrong after onStop >> onStart?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-lifecycle

I create a ProgressDialog in my onStart and then later on, after an async task returns, I hide/dismiss it.

When I jump to the homescreen and back, and re-instantiate a new ProgressDialog to the variable, the code later on still references the old memory address of the last time I set ProgressDialog.

I have tried a multitude of different approaches but I'm stumped. I can't seem to get a ProgressDialog to behave properly after the first start of the app. Could someone guide me in how to fix this, or suggest a different approach?

Thanks.

EDIT: I should mention that I tried using the same variable I set initially, instead of re-instantiating it, but hide/dismiss did nothing.

In onStart()

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
mProgressDialog.show();
```

Then later in my updateMap()

```
mProgressDialog.dismiss(); // Or hide()
```

This works fine the first run. But when the activity is stopped and restarted, the second block does not execute as expected.

EDIT 2:

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
```

onCreate()

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

onResume()

```
mProgressDialog.show();
```

updateMap()

```
mProgressDialog.hide();
```

It works the first run, but when the I jump to the homescreen and back, the ProgressDialog never hides. What's going on?!

Comment: Can you post what you have?

Comment: Are you sure the updateMap() gets called again when you go back in? Could you post the entire class?

Comment: Very sure. One thing I thought to try was since my updateMap is a callback from an asyncTask, that maybe it wasn't running the UI thread, but when I created a handler for the mainLooper, and tried hiding the ProgressDialog within a runnable there, it still didn't work.

        My class is my mainActivity. So it is quite large. I don't believe it's so much of an issue with my code, as it is very basic and straightforward. But instead my understanding of how ProgressDialogs are created. How are there multiple instances if I only reassign the same global variable?

Comment: I usually dismiss my dialogs by calling dismiss() not hide(). Also I instantiate them by doing something like this: mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title","dialog message", true);

Comment: I've bounced between dismiss and hide. I'm now using that new line to create my ProgressDialog, but I still need it to be global so i can dismiss it later in my code. Still not working. I'm not sure if I should try moving it to my singleton state class. At least there it wouldn't be global...

Comment: Interesting, you said you tried to run it on the main thread already. I would try using the built in runOnUiThread(Runnable) method for it if you have not already. Its available on any activity, so in your async task you could say MyActivity.runOnUiThread(Runnable) and try dismissing it in there. Otherwise I think we would need to see the full code to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the ProgressDialog variable to static. When the activity is recreated, it should reference the same ProgressDialog attached to that activity class, rather than a new one in a new instance of the class.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfect, and it makes sense to my problem.